# iptables returns me "no chain/target/match by that name"

Tags: centos, iptables

Been trying to run

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0:0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and I keep getting the above error message. Trying to set up openvpn on my server.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, venet0:0 is not valid, just use venet0, iptables does not care about interface labels.

The error itself is down to the fact that either you do not have the nat table kernel module loaded or you do, but don't have MASQUERADE.

Since this is OpenVZ, you would need to ask your host to provide it.

Comment: ok, thanks :)

found the solution here in case anyone needs it in future [http://kyl191.net/2012/09/getting-openvpn-to-work-on-an-openvz-vps/](http://kyl191.net/2012/09/getting-openvpn-to-work-on-an-openvz-vps/)